# Selenium button click in Python

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, webdriver

Im coding a **selenium** bot **with Python** which will be watching videos on different websites. I need it to press button to play video, but it doesnt work. I use Chrome webdriver and tried to use undetected_chromedriver, but nothing changed.

**My webdriver:**

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
```

or

```
browser = undetected_chromedriver.Chrome()
```

**My code is:**

`sendContinue = browser.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/a').click()`

It **worked** on login page, but not here.

**Button element:**

```
<button class="ytp-large-play-button ytp-button ytp-large-play-button-red-bg" aria-label="Смотреть"><svg height="100%" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 68 48" width="100%"><path class="ytp-large-play-button-bg" d="M66.52,7.74c-0.78-2.93-2.49-5.41-5.42-6.19C55.79,.13,34,0,34,0S12.21,.13,6.9,1.55 C3.97,2.33,2.27,4.81,1.48,7.74C0.06,13.05,0,24,0,24s0.06,10.95,1.48,16.26c0.78,2.93,2.49,5.41,5.42,6.19 C12.21,47.87,34,48,34,48s21.79-0.13,27.1-1.55c2.93-0.78,4.64-3.26,5.42-6.19C67.94,34.95,68,24,68,24S67.94,13.05,66.52,7.74z" fill="#f00"></path><path d="M 45,24 27,14 27,34" fill="#fff"></path></svg></button>
```

Can anyone solve this?

Comment: could you not just find the element by selecting it with the classname only?
this worked for me. just do:

`browser.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "ytp-large-play-button").click()`


should be the only element with the given class.

Comment: Thank you, but it didnt work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These kind of XPATH are unreliable, could you try the following?

```
sendContinue = browser.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[@class='.ytp-large-play-button.ytp-button']").click()
```

Off topic, but it sometimes help to wait for the button to appear, like:

```
def wait_click(driver, xpath, delay = 20):
    try:
        myElem = WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath)))
        myElem.click()
        return myElem
    except TimeoutException:
        print("Loading took too much time!")
```

You can call it with:

```
wait_click(driver, "//*[@class='.ytp-large-play-button.ytp-button.ytp-large-play-button-red-bg']")
```

Comment: Thank you, but nothing worked for me, just printed "Loading took too much time!", so I got TimeoutException

Comment: so then you need to set the delay longer. you get an timeout exception because 20 is too low, try it with a huge number like 1000000.

Comment: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits
when you read the documentation you would find that this delay in seconds, you probably tried it with 20 seconds, is the maximum amount of time that selenium tries to find the element, if your connection is so slow that the button is not there, even after 20 seconds you will get an TimeoutException, nothing weird happening here.

Comment: Can you go in your browser console (Ctrl + Shift + c) then confirm this plays it? $('.ytp-play-button').click() Also I saw mistakes in my answer and I corrected it, you may retry

Comment: when i plays it, i got r.fn.init [prevObject: r.fn.init(1)]

Comment: and your edited code doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

To interact with any ***clickable*** element ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.ytp-large-play-button.ytp-button.ytp-large-play-button-red-bg[aria-label='Смотреть'] > svg > path"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='ytp-large-play-button ytp-button ytp-large-play-button-red-bg' and @aria-label='Смотреть']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```